# javascript \d regular expression unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying use javascript regular expressions to do some matching and I found a really unusual behavior that I was hoping someone could explain.

The string I was trying to match was: " 0    (IR)  " and the code block was

```
finalRegEx = new RegExp("[0-9]");
match = finalRegEx.exec(str);
```

except that when I put "\d" instead of "[0-9]" it didn't find a match.  I'm really confused by this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use *RegExp* with `"\d"` to build the regular expression, the `"\d"` will result in just `"d"`. Either use two back slashes to escape the slash like `"\\d"` or simply use the [regular expression literals `/…/`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) instead:

```
match = /\d/.exec(str)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape it because you're using the constructor, otherwise it matches `d` literally:

```
new RegExp('\\d').test('1')
```

`new RegExp` should only be used for dynamic matching. Otherwise use a literal:

```
var foo = /\d/;
foo.test(1)
```

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic matching? matching against the contents of a variable?

Comment: creating the regex dynamically instead of hard coding it, such as in a loop, creating a new RegExp object per some changing variable.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to escape the backslash: `finalRegEx = new RegExp("\\d");`